# Set true/false seesion variable if user is logged in/out in ColdFusion Application.cfc?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I'm working on my Application.cfc page for my SPA. So far I was able to create simple test and there is one problem that I notice. Flag that I set when user is `loggedin` always indicates to `true`. Here is my Application.cf page example:

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false">
    <cfset APPLICATION.appStarted = now()>
    <cfset APPLICATION.appCode = 'SPA'>
    <cfset APPLICATION.title = "SPA Application">
    <cfset APPLICATION.errorEmails = "myemail@gmail.com">
    <cfset APPLICATION.CryptWord = randomSequence()>
    <cfset APPLICATION.AppStarted = true>
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>

<!--- Runs when your session starts --->
<cffunction  name="OnSessionStart" access="public" returntype="void" output="false">
    <!--- Clear the session. --->
    <cfset StructClear( SESSION ) />
    <cfset SESSION.loggedin = false>

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>

<!--- Run before the request is processed --->
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="thePage" type="string" required="true">
    <cfset var page = listLast(arguments.thePage,"/")>

    <cfif !listFindNoCase("Login.cfm,Login.cfc",page)>      
        <cfif !structKeyExists(session, "loggedin") OR session.loggedin EQ false>
            <cflocation url="Login.cfm" addToken="false">
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

As you can see above I first set some application variables in `onApplicationStart()` the `onSessionStart()` first I clear `SESSION` structure then set flag to false. Here is example of my Login.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="checkLogin" access="remote" output="false" returnType="boolean">
        <cfargument name="username" type="string" required="true">
        <cfargument name="password" type="string" required="true">

        <cfif arguments.username EQ "test" AND arguments.password EQ "test">
            <cfset SESSION.loggedin = true>
            <cfreturn true>
        <cfelse>
            <cfreturn false>
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then I use `cfdump` to check my `SESSION` variable on my `Login.cfm` (only has HTML form elements and JQuery function to submit the form). Doesn't matter if `checkLogin` function returns true or false value in loggedin variable is still equal to `true`. If anyone can see where I'm doing something wrong in my code please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: You are locating to a .cfm file and describing a .cfc file.

Comment: The only place you set `SESSION.loggedin = false` is in the `OnSessionStart()` event.  You should also add it to the `<cfelse>` block of your `login.cfc`.  And if if you have a `logout.cfm` you can add it there as well.

Comment: @DanBracuk it appears to me the login.cfc is called via ajax from the login.cfm which he described is a simple html form.

Comment: @user9263373 That's correct.  I have send an AJAX request from Login.cfm to Login.cfc to trigger cfcfuntion.

Comment: Great, but did you see my other comment?  If the only place that `SESSION.loggedin = false` gets set is in the `OnSessionStart()` event, then it only makes sense that it never goes false again (unless the session or application times out).  So based on the way you structured your code, you need to set it false in the `<cfelse>` block of your `login.cfc`.

Comment: @user9263373 I have tried that and works fine now. I was thinking since I had structClear() in onSessionStart() that should take care of that. Thanks.